# Projecting points on line and calculating distance from line start

Tags: qgis, point, projection-mathematics

I have

- a vector layer with a number of points which correspond to magnetic targets
- axis retrieved from AutoCAD

**The task** is to project the points on the axis and then calculate the distance of each projected point from the start of the axis. Ideally, I would like the calculated distance to be on the same table as the points so I can know which point each distance refers to.

Moreover, it would be nice to know the perpendicular distance of each point from the reference axis. A picture of the above problem is also presented below.

[image: Problem_example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start the Field Calculator on your point layer's attribute table.

Create a new field by an expression below:

```
line_locate_point(geometry:=geometry(get_feature('NaMy_FSR', 'id', '1')), point:=$geometry)
```

Assuming:

- Your line layer name is : `NaMy_FSR`
- The line has an attribute value `1` in the `'id'` field. (You can use any field to distinguish the line).

---

[EDIT]

As to the distance `the perpendicular distance of each point from the reference axis`;

Not sure if this works, but will you try:

```
distance(closest_point(geometry(get_feature(‘NaMy_FSR’, ‘id’, ‘1’)), geometry), $geometry)
```

[revision]

```
distance(closest_point(geometry(get_feature(‘NaMy_FSR’, ‘id’, ‘1’)), $geometry), $geometry)
```

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the projection distance from the line ?

Comment: Hi @stamatis Yes, I think it is possible. Will you post a new question or edit your current question to include this additional requirement?

Comment: Question edited. Looking forward for the answer :)

Comment: @stamatis Added another syntax in `[EDIT]` section. Hopefully it works, but other specialists at this board may help you better.

Comment: @Kazuhito, does it play any role which CRS is applied or which CRS the layers are saved in?

Comment: @Kazuhito thank you very much for you assist and sharing your knowledge, looks like though that it returns null results :/

Comment: @Taras Thanks for the pointer. I think the CRS have to be the same among layers.

Comment: @stamatis Sorry, I think I made typo mistake. Not `distance(closest_point(geometry(get_feature(‘NaMy_FSR’, ‘id’, ‘1’)), geometry), $geometry)` but `distance(closest_point(geometry(get_feature(‘NaMy_FSR’, ‘id’, ‘1’)), $geometry), $geometry)`

Comment: @stamatis, which CRS are you working with? Do your layers share a mutual CRS with your project?

Comment: I am working on ESPG2100 and yes layers share the same CRS

Comment: @Kazuhito maybe i am pushing this too far but could i get also something like a sign so i know if it is left or right from the axis ? And another one (the last one i promise) could i also get a layer of the projected points on the axis ?

Comment: @stamatis Both questions are interesting, definitely. Will you post them as new questions? For the first one, I recommend to look into `azimuth()` function. I have no idea about the latter one, which would require experts' help.

Comment: @Kazuhito I ll do as you say. For the moment thank you very much for you help :)